# First argument indexing

Tags: indexing, prolog

I want to know how smart first argument indexing is implemented on various Prolog implementations.

In particular, simple type-test goals like `integer/1` right after a clause "neck" *could* contribute to better indexing.
Consider:

```
foo(h(X),X).
foo([],nil).
foo([_|_],cons).
foo(X,Y) :- integer(X), Y = n(X).
```

With this clause ordering I would like the goal `foo([],_)` to succeed **without** leaving any useless choicepoints.

Unfortunately, SWI Prolog does not figure it out:

```
?- length(Xs,10),
   maplist(=([]),Xs),
   statistics(trailused,T1),
   maplist(foo,Xs,Ys),
   statistics(trailused,T2).

T1 = 5792,
T2 = 5968,
Xs = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
Ys = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil] ...
```

Do other Prolog implementations do better?

Comment: Please note the irregularity, even impurity, of your example: While it is all fine for `foo(X,Y) when nonvar(X)`, it gets quite illogical for `X` being a variable: The first three clauses succeed, while the last fails. Optimizing for this particular mode appears to be a waisted effort: It would not occur in any pure program.

Comment: @false. The actual use I had in mind was more along the lines of "the first argument is either inf or sup or an integer X" (without the need for boxing the integer)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAP is another Prolog system providing extending indexing of predicate clauses:

```
$ yap
YAP 6.3.4 (x86_64-darwin14.3.0): Wed Apr 22 22:26:34 WEST 2015
 ?- [user].
 % consulting user_input...
foo(h(X),X).
|     foo([],nil).
|     foo([_|_],cons).
|     foo(X,Y) :- integer(X), Y = n(X).
|      % consulted user_input in module user, 1 msec 0 bytes
true.
 ?- foo([],_).
true.
```

Some relevant papers on YAP indexing features are:

- [Demand-Driven Indexing of Prolog Clauses](http://user.it.uu.se/~kostis/Papers/iclp07.pdf)
- [On Just in Time Indexing of Dynamic Predicates in Prolog](http://cracs.fc.up.pt/node/4169)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org) system does this.

As you suggest, it takes into account a number of simple built-in predicates (such as `integer/1, =/2, !/0`) for indexing purposes.  Your example then executes deterministically, without choicepoints, for all calls of `foo/2` with the first argument instantiated.  Moreover, ECLiPSe would do this on any argument, not just the first.

You can find a little more detail in the paper [ECLiPSe - from LP to CLP](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4240).

To answer your followup question: No extra VM features are necessary, the generated VM code looks like this:

```
foo / 2:
    switch_on_type           a(1) 
            list:           ref(L5)
            structure:      ref(L1)
            bignum:         ref(L7)
            []:             ref(L4)
            integer:        ref(L7)
            meta:           ref(L0)
label(L0):
    try                      0     2     ref(L1) 
    retry                    0     ref(L3) 
    trust                    0     ref(L5) 
label(L1):
    get_structure            a(1)     h / 1     ref(L2) 
    write_value              a(2) 
    ret                  
label(L2):
    read_value               a(2) 
    ret                  
label(L3):
    get_nil                  a(1) 
label(L4):
    get_atom                 a(2)     nil 
    ret                  
label(L5):
    get_list                 a(1)     ref(L6) 
    write_void               2 
label(L6):
    get_atom                 a(2)     cons 
    ret                  
label(L7):
    get_structure            a(2)     n / 1     ref(L8) 
    write_value              a(1) 
    ret                  
label(L8):
    read_value               a(1) 
    ret
```

Comment: To avoid code explosion, ECLiPSe uses a compromise strategy: the compiler creates indexes for every argument where this might be useful, but at runtime only one of them is used. Therefore, for a predicate `p(a,1). p(a,2). p(b,2). p(a,3).` the goals `p(b,Y)` and `p(X,1)` are deterministic, but `p(a,2)` still leaves a choicepoint.

Comment: No VM modifications are necessary for taking `integer/1` etc into account. For indexing non-first arguments you may need a slight generalization of the existing instructions. As for disadvantages: with the actually implemented multi-argument scheme one can construct pathological examples where runtime behaviour is worse than with first-argument-only. This could be avoided by having a bias for the first argument, but we chose not to do that.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know clause indexing in Prolog is based only on the syntax of the predicate arguments (usually only the first one) so that it can be done at compile time. In your example moving the last clause to the top and inserting a cut after `integer(X)` will, at least in some implementations, cause the other clauses to be indexed and a single choice-point would be initially created for a call to this predicate. Looking at the first goal in the body would slow down the indexing process with, in general, a too small benefit in the execution time.

Comment: What you are asking for is a feature only applicable to clauses of a particular format  and the gain in efficiency it would lead to does not pay for the increased complexity of the indexing mechanism.

Comment: I do not see your point in refusing to use the cut: in general any Prolog program wil have it either explicitly or implicitly (by using conditionals and similar constructs). As to using functors in order to enable indexing it is standard practice in Prolog programming: I also do not see why to refrain from it.

Comment: I agree the impact of a more complex indexing mechanism will be on the compilation time. I do not understand what you mean by "pure code": if you leave out the cut and its derivatives (`not/1`, conditionals, and so on) and also non-logic predicates like type-testing predicates (like `integer/1`), I/O, arithmetic and so on, you stand with a pure logic language (the Horn-clause predicate calculus) that is not powerful enough to be used as a programming language for any purpose. But maybe you do not need the power of a Turing machine for what you want to program.

Comment: Your quote is unacceptable and it seems you do not understood what I wrote. Please do read a some more scientifically sound textbook on the matter such as W. F. Clocksin and C. S. Mellish, Programming in Prolog,  Springer-Verlag, 1994 or R. O'Keefe, The Craft of Prolog, The MIT Press, 1990.

Comment: I did explain what "pure Prolog" means in the technical literature: the Horn-clause calculus using the resolution principle as inference rule, a pure logic language with no side effects. Maybe you wish to read the article on resolution, J. A. Robinson, A Machine-oriented Logic Based on the Resolution Principle, JACM vol. 12, 1965,  and/or the standard book on Logic Programming semantics: J. W. Lloyd, Foundations of Logic Programming, 2nd ed., Springer-Verlag, 1987.

Comment: You only don't get a good amortization if you heavily assert and retract clauses. But for static clauses the indexing is only done once, so there should be a splendid amortization effect for analysing the body of a clause.

Answer (score -1):

We recently added guard indexing to Jekejeke Prolog. The following guard indexing exists already for a while:

```
p(..., X, ...) :- ..., var(X), ...
```

We extended this treatment now to further guards. This will be available in the upcoming release 1.3.4:

```
p(..., X, ...) :- ..., X = f(...), ...
p(..., X, ...) :- ..., functor(X, f, ...), ...
```

These new guards work fine, since they generate additional clause keys that are already part of the existing indexes.

But currently our existing index does not allow to lookup a Prolog type, only atomic values, so we cannot realize an integer(X) guard at the moment, even though the detection itself would not be very difficult.

The realization is very simple, we do not need to lookup some instructions. Instead we can directly search the body literals in the simpler Jekejeke Prolog intermediate format:

**Open Source: Java class Index, method getGuard()**
https://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-devel/blob/master/jekrun/headless/jekpro/model/rope/Index.java#L105