# Choice points and Redo's in Prolog

Tags: prolog, choice-point

After asking a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391973/when-is-the-redo-port-called-with-new-variables-in-trace-0-and-when-not/45393321?noredirect=1#comment77769720_45393321) about when exactly a `Redo` is called in Prolog with new variables, or when it is attempted with the same, I thought I figured it out. In the following piece of code, however, I thought that an additional `Redo` were to be called, but that does not seem to be the case.

My knowledge base is the following:

```
location(desk,office).
location(apple,kitchen).
location(flashlight,desk).
location('washing machine',cellar).
location(nani,'washing machine').
location(broccoli,kitchen).
location(crackers,kitchen).
location(computer,office).

edible(apple).
edible(crackers).
```

My query was

```
?-location(X,kitchen),edible(X).
```

with the following trace:

```
   Call: (9) location(_5612, kitchen) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(apple, kitchen) ? creep
   Call: (9) edible(apple) ? creep
   Exit: (9) edible(apple) ? creep
X = apple ;
   Redo: (9) location(_5612, kitchen) ? creep       <====
   Exit: (9) location(broccoli, kitchen) ? creep
   Call: (9) edible(broccoli) ? creep
   Fail: (9) edible(broccoli) ? creep
   Redo: (9) location(_5612, kitchen) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(crackers, kitchen) ? creep
   Call: (9) edible(crackers) ? creep
   Exit: (9) edible(crackers) ? creep
X = crackers.
```

Why is there not an additional `Redo` after the first solution along the lines of `Redo: (9) edible(apple)` (which would then fail, before going on to the next `Redo`) since there is still another fact in the code with the functor `edible`, which would mean that there was a choice point that created? I found an annotated trace of the same query [here](http://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/a4comqry.php). I will post a short snippet from it, because it has the additional `Redo` that I feel is missing here:

[image: screenshot of webpage]

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what is to be expected in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: So in this case it is possible that it is just due to the specific Prolog environment I am using?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is there some kind of 'vanilla' or 'standard' Prolog environment for beginners where those kinds of enhancements are limited, in order to see more clearly how all the small details work and interact?

Comment: I should have you ask `Is there some kind of 'vanilla' or 'standard' Prolog environment for beginners where those kinds of enhancements are limited, in order to see more clearly how all the small details work and interact?` as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the documentation then.

Comment: Of interest: [First argument indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29605132/1243762) SO Q&A

Comment: How do I close this question properly without an answer to accept?

Comment: Of interest: [User Deﬁned Indexing](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ricroc/homepage/publications/stampa/2009-ICLP-B.pdf) The start of the paper gives an overview of how indexing works in Prolog.

Comment: Of interest: [Just In Time Indexing (JITI) utilities](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/f60b89267e04e730d26efcb19b515a88b917338a/library/prolog_jiti.pl)

Comment: Of interest: [Test unit for Just-In-Time indexing](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/c31d8328b0b351d5d2ab9433d19b026e827758ed/src/Tests/core/test_jit.pl)

Comment: Of interest: [pl-index.c](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/22bcb326cf175fa5f3818410d5a87ba0045f289b/src/pl-incl.h)

Comment: I am not finding a runtime switch, command line switch or a compile time switch in SWI-Prolog to limit the enhancements. I can't say for sure this is not one, but it would be a lot of work to add and keep updated.

Comment: Of interest: [Clean vs. defaulty representations](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/data)

Comment: Of interest: [SLDNF Draw](http://endif.unife.it/it/ricerca-1/aree-di-ricerca/informazione/ingegneria-informatica/software/sldnf-draw/sldnf-draw) - SWI-Prolog Package [sldnfdraw](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=sldnfdraw)

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with [Indexing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary).

From SWI-Prolog Glossary of Terms

> Indexing is a technique used to quickly select candidate clauses of a
> predicate for a specific goal. In most Prolog systems, indexing is
> done (only) on the first argument of the head. If this argument is
> instantiated to an atom, integer, float or compound term with functor,
> hashing is used to quickly select all clauses where the first argument
> may unify with the first argument of the goal. SWI-Prolog supports
> just-in-time and multi-argument indexing. See section 2.18.

This is one of those cases where the concept and implementation diverge.

Think of it like this, if you were to write the logic engine for Prolog and then the users wanted it to work faster you would add enhancements that made it faster, but in so doing, the way it works would not be the same as the conceptual model.

Now that the engine has enhancements you should really have a switch that turns off those enhancements when debugging so that you see what is really happening.

From [Prolog Programming in Depth](http://math.uni.lodz.pl/%7Ekowalcr/PPL/PrologBook.pdf) by
Michael A. Covington
Donald Nute
Andr´e Vellino

Sec. 4.14. Indexing  pg. 111

> When a Prolog system executes a query, it doesn’t have to search the entire knowledge base for a matching clause. All Prologs use INDEXING (a hashing function or lookup table) to go directly to the right predicate. For example, with FAMILY.PL, a query to mother/2 does not search the clauses for father/2.
>
> Most modern Prologs use indexing to go further than that. They index, not only on the predicate and arity, but also on the principal functor of the ﬁrst argument. For example, if you have the knowledge base

```
a(b).  
a(c).  

d(e).
d(f).
```

> then the query ‘?- d(f).’ not only won’t search the clauses for a/1, it also won’t look at d(e). It goes straight to d(f), which is the only clause whose predicate, arity, and ﬁrst argument match those in the query.

### Question in comment

> Is there some kind of 'vanilla' or 'standard' Prolog environment for beginners where those kinds of enhancements are limited, in order to see more clearly how all the small details work and interact?

### Meta-interpreters

From: [A Couple of Meta-interpreters in Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/acomip/)

> An interpreter for a language similar or identical to its own implementation language is called meta-interpreter (MI).

Learning about Prolog MIs are an excellent way to understand how Prolog works and also learn about MIs which are extremely useful, e.g.

[Use of Prolog for developing a new programming language](http://www.erlang.se/publications/prac_appl_prolog.pdf)

### Implementation in another language

Another way to see how unification works is to use the unification algorithm with backtracking implemented in another language and then use that to enhance the code outputting information you want to see. There is a [miniProlog](http://plzoo.andrej.com/language/miniprolog.html) written in OCaml, but I don't suspect that many people know OCaml.

A lot of the more extensive books on Artificial Intelligence implement it.

["Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/987937635) by Perter Norvig (Lisp)

["Artificial Intelligence Structures and Strategies for Complex Problem Solving"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/183611012) by George F Luger (Pseudo Code)

Prolog implementations can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/). [smallProlog](https://github.com/a-yiorgos/smallprolog) is very basic and done in C.

And for the theory of unification there is the classic in

["Handbook of automated reasoning"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/46810789) Chapter 8

[Unification theory](https://www.cs.bu.edu/fac/snyder/publications/UnifChapter.pdf) by Franz Baader and Wayne Snyder

### Derivation trees

See: [Prolog derivation trees, choices, and unification](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Ejrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/3_1.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can visualize the redo with Byrd's box model, in this
model a predicate call P has 4 ports:

```
            +-------+
--- call -->|       |--- exit -->
            |   P   | 
<-- fail ---|       |<-- redo ---
            +-------+
```

As a rule when there are no cuts for every exit there is a redo. And for every
call there is ultimately a fail sometime later, except in SWI-Prolog (and maybe some other Prolog systems?):

- redo's are supressed when P deterministically succeeded
- fail's are supressed when P deterministically succeeded

Deterministic success usually results for the last clause
in an index bouquet, and is seen in the non-debug top-level 
that the semicolon prompt is supressed. See also here:

[Making "deterministic success" of Prolog goals explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823117/making-deterministic-success-of-prolog-goals-explicit)

In Jekejeke Prolog this "optimization" has not yet been implemented 
for the debugger. It has also deterministic success, but not when the
debugger is on, thats why there are two different traces:

**SWI-Prolog Trace:**

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.5.8)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.

?- location(X,kitchen),edible(X).
   Call: (9) location(_3980, kitchen) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(apple, kitchen) ? creep
   Call: (9) edible(apple) ? creep
   Exit: (9) edible(apple) ? creep
X = apple 
   Redo: (9) location(_3980, kitchen) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(broccoli, kitchen) ? creep
   Call: (9) edible(broccoli) ? creep
   Fail: (9) edible(broccoli) ? creep
   Redo: (9) location(_3980, kitchen) ? creep
   Exit: (9) location(crackers, kitchen) ? creep
   Call: (9) edible(crackers) ? creep
   Exit: (9) edible(crackers) ? creep
X = crackers.
```

**Jekejeke Prolog Trace:**

```
Jekejeke Prolog 2, Development Environment 1.2.2
(c) 1985-2017, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- location(X,kitchen),edible(X).
    0 Call location(X, kitchen) ? 
    0 Exit location(apple, kitchen) ? 
    0 Call edible(apple) ? 
    0 Exit edible(apple) ? 
X = apple ;
    0 Redo edible(apple) ? 
    0 Fail edible(apple) ? 
    0 Redo location(apple, kitchen) ? 
    0 Exit location(broccoli, kitchen) ? 
    0 Call edible(broccoli) ? 
    0 Fail edible(broccoli) ? 
    0 Redo location(broccoli, kitchen) ? 
    0 Exit location(crackers, kitchen) ? 
    0 Call edible(crackers) ? 
    0 Exit edible(crackers) ? 
X = crackers ;
    0 Redo edible(crackers) ? 
    0 Fail edible(crackers) ? 
    0 Redo location(crackers, kitchen) ? 
    0 Fail location(X, kitchen) ? 
No
```